# Custom UICellView not adding subviews

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview

I'm using a simple custom UICellView like this:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed:204/255.0f green:62/255.0f blue:56/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

        // Initialization code
        //Styling the cell:
        UIView* spacer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40,200, 350, 100)];
        [spacer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:180/255.0f green:56/255.0f blue:61/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
        //
        UIView* BlockNumber = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40,200, 179, 175)];
        [BlockNumber setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        [self.contentView addSubview:spacer];
        [self.contentView addSubview:BlockNumber];

        //

        self.backgroundColor=color;
    }



    return self;
}
```

I tried checking the cell's subviews with a for loop, and they do seem to be there, although the won't show up inside the cell view.
However, the self.backgroundColor actually changes its color, but when it comes to adding views, it won't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are adding views under the cell view. 
Try replacing

```
CGRectMake(40,200, 350, 100)
```

With

```
CGRectMake(40, 0, 350, 100)
```